# Ubuntu E: Failed to fetch

Tags: apt-get, ubuntu-16.04

I run the update on Ubuntu 16.04 LTE by :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

My problem is the :

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding xenial to the repo

echo 'deb http://download.fpcomplete.com/ubuntu xenial main'|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fpco.list

Comment: Go to ubuntu settings -> software updates...Under Ubuntu software check if   bottom most option i.e cdrom with ubuntu is checked or not...Uncheck it

Comment: Did u try the entire line or just partially tried in terminal

Comment: echo 'deb http://download.fpcomplete.com/ubuntu xenial main'|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fpco.list

Comment: Now if i colse stettings i chave : E:Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fpco.list (URI parse), E:The list of sources could not be read.